# Class not found for service in custom module

Tags: commerce, event-subscribers, symfony-services

I am trying to create an event subscriber service in a custom module and I keep getting a "Class not found" error.
The module directory is modules/custom/avgc
The class is in src/EventSubscriber.php
This is my avgc.services.yml:

```
services:
  avgc.order_fulfillment_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\avgc\EventSubscriber\OrderFulfillmentSubscriber
    arguments: ['@language_manager', '@plugin.manager.mail']
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

and this is EventSubscriber.php up to the class declaration:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\avgc\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\state_machine\Event\WorkflowTransitionEvent;
use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
 * Sends an email when the order transitions to Fulfillment.
 */
class OrderFulfillmentSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
....
```

Everything is copypasted from
https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/orders/workflows/react-to-workflow-transitions
All I did was change my_module to avgc, and reading the answers to previous questions on this topic everything would seem to be in order, but it isn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced, was solved by a cache clear, or was a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: I'm new here and may not have proper knowledge, but actually, this was not solved by a cache clear and it was not a typographical error. It was a conceptual error on my part concerning the placement of the class file in relation to the namespace, and was only solved thanks to the accepted answer. So I think it might be useful for someone else in future.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This question was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. To help them, the answer should be generic enough to be applicable to every class a module could implement. The question should be generic enough to make them understand the answer doesn't apply only to event subscribers and that isn't related only to services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `namespace Drupal\avgc\EventSubscriber` and a class name of `OrderFulfillmentSubscriber`, the class file should be in `/avgc/src/EventSubscriber/OrderFulfillmentSubscriber.php` to get discovered.

Comment: Yes,, that did it!
Thank you